# log IP with php

Tags: php, ip

i found this script online:

```
<?php
$v_ip = $REMOTE_ADDR; $v_date = date("l d F H:i:s");

$fp = fopen("ips.txt", "a"); fputs($fp, "IP: $v_ip - DATE: $v_date\n\n"); fclose($fp);

?>
```

creating the entry works - however, the IP is not displayed. the entries created look like this:

```
IP: - DATE: Wednesday 09 March 03:36:15

IP: - DATE: Wednesday 09 March 03:36:41
```

what's the problem?

Comment: This script is very old (most likely PHP4) and uses `register_globals=on` which is highly insecure. Please use another source for learning php.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The variable is

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

so you need to change yours to

```
$v_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to populate $REMOTE_ADDR with something. In this case, you would do

```
$REMOTE_ADDR  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

or change your script to be

```
$v_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; $v_date = date("l d F H:i:s");
```